# Ajax long polling with Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, sockets

We need to build a small Javascript widget with bidirectional data capabilities. It's main functionality is to send messages to/receive updates from server. The server will use node.js/socket.io combination for realtime response with private room/channel feature.

Using the socket.io-client.js library out of the box is considered not resource efficient in our case. Being a Javascript widget, it's ideal to keep the size small, e.g., under 100K. The library alone is well over 100K.

So, another option is to not use the socket.io-client.js library, but just use vanilla Aajax long polling technique. We've never done this, and don't know how much work required to make this happen.

Has anyone done this before? If so, can you share your experience?

Thanks.

Comment: The minified version of the client is about 64K in size (and [`engine.io-client`](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client) is about 42K).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But that's still some weight we want to avoid if simple Ajax code is good enough.

Comment: It looks like [it's been done before](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=long+polling).